# Conditional popup text, onmouseover depending of the value in cell of a table. Html, javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in html.

I want that when I mouse over a cell, it pop-ups a text. The text popped-up, should depend of the text inside of the cell.

Example of an html table:

City   number
Paris    1454
Madrid   1345
Roma     684

If I mouseover a City (Paris), it should pop-up the country (France).

I have seen partial solutions, (
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp), but I don´t know how to solve the conditional part of the pop-up.

Thank you

Comment: Please give us your HTML DOM of the table, and the popup script you really want to use

Comment: consider adding the `HTML` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need a `hover`

```
The <abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948.
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp

Comment: Thank you Hubi. It solved my problem easily. Thanks to the other answers too, I'll have in mind this other solutions for another.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to have "hover-popups" in HTML. You can add a `title` property to set the text shown in the popup:

`<td title="France">Paris</td>`

You can also set this via JavaScript:

`td.title = "France"`

*I don't know if that is what you're looking for, but if it is, it's easier that way*

Answer (score 0):

Static generated Table:-

```js
var list = [{
  city: "Italy",
  country: "Rome"
}, {
  city: "Belgium",
  country: "Brussels"
}];
var statusCol = "";
var table = '<table><tr><th>City</th><th>Country</th></tr>';
var ID = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var row = "<tr  class='staff-row' >";
  row += '<td title=' + list[i].city + '>' + list[i].city + '</td>';
  row += '<td  title=' + list[i].country + '>' + list[i].country + '</td>'
  row += "</tr>"
  ID++;
  table += row;
}
table += '</table>';
$('#DisplayTable').html(table);
$('#DisplayTable').tooltip({
  'show': true,
  'selector': '.staff-row',
  'placement': 'bottom',
  'title': function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tds = $this.find('td');
    return
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
<script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
Static Table:-
<table class="popup">
  <tr onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <th title="City">City</th>
    <th title="Country">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td title="Delhi">Delhi</td>
    <td title="India">India</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td title="Paris">Paris</td>
    <td title="France">France</td>
  </tr>
</table><br /> Dynamic Table:-
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
```

Comment: What is `myFunction(event)` and how does that answer this (off topic, should be closed) question?

Comment: @Rob I am trying to generate the dynamic table that's why I have done that mistake. sorry about that... :-) Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing a DOM like that :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th scope="col">Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Paris </th>
      <td>1454</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Madrid</th>
      <td>1345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Roma</th>
      <td>684</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Assuming you have a JS code that show the popup on hover.

You can use the `data` attribute to set the country on each city cell:

```
<th scope="row" data-country="France">Paris</th>
```

And patch the JS code to use it:

```
const elts = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
for (let elt of elts) {
  elt.addEventListener("mouseover", (evt) => {
    const country = evt.target.getAttribute('data-country');
    yourPopupScript(country); // this trigger your popup, and you can write the country into
  });
}
```